# How do I include the request module npm to send to Lambda

Tags: npm, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

I'm trying to include the request module to build an ALexa skill that makes web request. Is there a certain way I have to package it in the zip file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple use npm to install request, and include node_modules in your zip.
So run :

```
npm install request
```

Now, say your handler is index.js, after zipping your project the structure should be something like this:

```
index.js
node_modules/request
```